# Entity Framework model doesn't work after an AppPool Recycle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

We're using Entity Framework version 5.0. The classes were created from Model-First, but now are code-first. Examples:

```
public class tTableName: EntityTypeConfiguration<EntityName> {
    public tTableName() {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Column2)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255);

        this.Property(t => t.Column5)
                .HasMaxLength(5);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("tTableName");
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        this.Property(t => t.Column2).HasColumnName("Column2");
        this.Property(t => t.Column3).HasColumnName("Column3");
        this.Property(t => t.Column4).HasColumnName("Column4");
        this.Property(t => t.Column5).HasColumnName("Column5");
        this.Property(t => t.Column6).HasColumnName("Column6");
    }
}

public class EntityName{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Column2{ get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Column4 { get; set; }
    public string Column5 { get; set; }
    public int? Column6 { get; set; }
}
```

In my DataContext class, I've overridden `OnModelCreating` and pass in the tTableName classes one at a time. This was all created for me by reverse-engineering my Database (Schema-First? Database-First?).

So the Database exists, the schema is populated, and we aren't using any EF migrations or initializers. 
`Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);`

**The Problem**

When our application starts up, everything loads and initializes just fine. I do a database query in my Application_OnStart just to make sure it does work. But, at some point after running fine for 24 hours, after an Application Pool Recycle, the application stops working. Restarting IIS, Recycling the App Pool, Even rebooting the machine has no effect. The error that I get is:

> The entity TypeName is not part of the model for the current context.

This isn't so nice. It worked a moment ago. But nothing I do can get it to work again. *EXCEPT* uploading a fresh binary or making a change to the /bin folder. This causes something to reset so that Entity Framework is convinced to rebuild the model. When tracing the code, and looking at my logs, it appears that Entity Framework has somehow "forgotten" the database model and is just **skipping** the ModelCreating step when the application is restarting.

I assume that Entity Framework is building up the model and then emitting it or saving it to *something* which is why it doesn't feel the need to call ModelCreating. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611591/192536), Entity Framework (as of 4.0) will cache the model, but only reuse it when creating a new DbContext within the same AppDomain. So what could cause the model to become corrupted? How can I force model-rebuilding in Application_OnStart?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I did have some other code, but mainly it was because I was separating my Entities and my EntityModelConfiguration classes into separate projects (we had just too many) and sometimes the ASP.NET runtime would load my assemblies in a different order, and sometimes it wouldn't have loaded them yet (or at all). So I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5599581/192536) to pre-load all of my assemblies from my /bin folder during application startup.